# Why can't I get the request result form Alamofire

Tags: json, swift, alamofire

I can't get the result of Alamofire request.So,I created ouput of an array that I got from json async call.I can't get the resultArray out of dispatch {...}.When I add println to debug the code.The second one appear first before the first one.
All i want to resultArray to get the data from Alamofire to display in UIPickerView.Please Help!!!

Here is my code

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource{

@IBOutlet var venuePicker : UIPickerView?

var resultOld = [String:String]() // i need it to get only value from json

var result : [String]?

let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()

override func viewDidLoad() {

    if result == nil {
        populateVenues ({ (error, result) -> Void in
            self.result = result as? [String]
            self.venuePicker?.reloadAllComponents()
        })
    }
}

func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    if result != nil{
        return result!.count// Why i can't use result?.count instead of result!.count
    }
    else{
        return 0
    }
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {
    if result != nil{
        println(result)
        return result?[row]
    }
    else{
        return "..."
    }
}

func populateVenues(completion : (error: NSError?,result : AnyObject?) -> Void){
    Alamofire.request(.POST, "http://xxxx.xxxx.xxx").responseJSON() {
        (_, _, jsonData, error) in

        if error == nil{
            var venues = JSON(jsonData!)

            for (k, v) in venues {

                self.resultOld[k] = v.arrayValue[0].stringValue
            }

            self.result = self.resultOld.values.array

            completion(error: nil,result: self.result)
        }
        else{
            println("Error!!")
            completion(error: error!,result: nil)
        }
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

}
```

Here is my output at console

```
The 2st result array : []
The 1st result array : [ORIX Kobe Nyusatsu, NPS Sendai Nyusatsu, JU Gunma, KAA Kyoto, JU Ibaraki, USS Gunma, ISUZU Kobe, NAA Osaka Nyusatsu, SMAP Sapporo Nyusatsu, L-Up PKobeNyusatsu, ARAI Sendai, TAA Minami Kyushu, NPS Oyama Nyusatsu, CAA Tokyo, JU Toyama, USS Shikoku, NPS Gifu Nyusatsu, NAA Fukuoka, KCAA Yamaguchi, JU Fukuoka, LAA Kansai, JAA, TAA Kinki, USS Sapporo, JU Miyagi, USS Fukuoka, JU Tokyo]
```

Please i really need to know what is happening to me and why i can't get the result of async call first.

Comment: async calls take time. set up a completion block in your populateVenue function and put the 2st result array in the completion block. That way it will only print after the full populateVenue is done

Comment: can you suggest me how to get the data first.please,any code suggestion is appreciated.Thank u

Comment: Ok I posted an answer with very basic code of what I mean by a completion block.

Comment: @Rob>reloading the data,didn't work out.                                                  @ad121,thanks.If you don't mind,can you give me a solution.

Comment: now i got second array inside viewDidLoad,but it only work inside populateVenues{}..i can't still get resultArray,Any Help?I have updated the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So asynchronous calls are executed on another thread. Thus, when you call the function `populateVenue()`, the `populateVenue()` function is not completing before the `println("The 2st result array : \(self.resultArray)" )`. If you set up your `populateVenue()` to have a closure, this won't happen.
Example:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

   super.viewDidLoad()

   populateVenue( { (error, result) -> Void in 
      println("The 2st result array : \(self.resultArray)" )
   })
}

func populateVenue(completion: (error: NSError?, result: AnyObject?) -> Void) {
    Alamofire.request(.POST, "http://localhost:8080/ws/automobile/global/auction/latest/venues").responseJSON() {
    (_, _, jsonData, error) in

       if error == nil {
          // do whatever you need
          // Note that result is whatever data you retrieved
          completion(nil, result)
       } else {
           println("Errror")
           completion(error!, nil)
       }
   }
}
```

Edit:

I am still trying to understand your problem, but this is my best shot. Note that I have no idea what the purpose of resultOld is so I removed it. If you absolutely need it you can add it back in. My design here is to make the properties optional, and return the result in the completion block. Then in viewDidLoad, you can initialize the property array and reload your screen.

```
@IBOutlet var venuePicker : UIPickerView?

// Try making this optional so you can tell when the network call is completed
var result: [String]?

var error = "Error"

let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    if result == nil {
       populateVenues ( { (result) -> Void in
          self.result = result
          self.venuePicker?.reloadAllComponents()
       })
    }
}

func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
     if result != nil {
        return result.count
     } else {
        return 0
     }
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {

    return result[row]
}

func populateVenues(completion : (result : [String]?) -> Void){
    Alamofire.request(.POST, "http://localhost:8080/ws/automobile/global/auction/latest/venues").responseJSON() {
        (_, _, jsonData, error) in

        if error == nil{
            var venues = JSON(jsonData!)

            for (k, v) in venues {

                resultOld[k] = v.arrayValue[0].stringValue

            }

            result = resultOld.values.array

            completion(result: result)
        }
        else{
            println("Error!!")
            completion(result: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: now i got second array inside viewDidLoad,but it only work inside populateVenues{}..i can't still get resultArray,Any Help_?

Comment: I am so sorry, I forgot to specify the types of the variables in the completion block. I updated my answer.

Comment: Also, I don't know what you mean by your second comment. Can you clarify?

Comment: as you see,the result[] cannot use out of the closure when function populateVenue is called.So,in order to display the data in the UIPickerView,delegate and datasource methods of UIPickerView must be return.So,how do i solve this?Thank you

Comment: I updated the code at counting the result,you will see what its happening to me.I am new to async programming.Please help

Comment: Ok I updated my answer again as best I could given the info to me

Comment: i update the code..i got error in the syntax which i can't solve.The error are show in comment.My real problem is i want to display the data that are from json at uipickerview.Please help.Thank you for your answer.

Comment: I updated the answer...I got it now...But it has to wait for a while to appear data on uipicker view.Thanks ad121...Thank you so much.I got one question to ask.In numberOfRowsInComponent function,i leave comment the question.Why i can't type result?.count.

Comment: Since you already checked that result != nil, there is no case where the optional would be nil. Hence you should just unwrap the optional using ! instead of ?.

Comment: i get it...Thanks for your help..about async call all the way.Thank you.