# How to properly access JSON response data in a custom class with Swift?

Tags: ios, json, swift

I have accessed the data I want from my JSON, but my postTitles array is not behaving like I expect it to. I'm still wrapping my head around Swift, and want to test my Express.js REST API on iOS as the client.

```
import Foundation

class Post {

    var className = "Post"

    var postTitles:[String] = []

    class func loadPosts() -> Post {

        let post = Post()

        request(.GET, "http://localhost:8080/posts").responseJSON {
        (_, _, JSON, _) in

            if let json = JSON as? [String : NSArray] {

                if let data = json["data"] {

                    if let postData: AnyObject = data as AnyObject? {

                        for var i = 0; i < postData.count; ++i {

                            if let postTitle = postData[i]["title"] as? String {

                                post.postTitles.append(postTitle)

                                // prints out:
                                // [The After]
                                // [The After, The Kraken]
                                // [The After, The Kraken, The Cream]

                            }

                        }

                    }

                }

            }

        }

        // prints: "Post"
        println(post.className)
        // prints: []
        // Why won't it print [The After, The Kraken, The Cream]?
        println(post.postTitles)

        return post

    }

}
```

Why is the array empty?

Comment: The request is asynchronous. So it will print `postTitles` before the request is complete. `return` statements wont work for this kind of function as expected. Instead set up a completion block for your `loadPosts` function and pass the post object through that completion block.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29452563/how-do-i-return-something-from-alamofire/29452838#29452838 here is a past answer on how to set up a completion block. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28207185/why-cant-i-get-the-request-result-form-alamofire/28207366#28207366 here is another.

Comment: ad121, thank you! Took me a second to set it up, but it's a good technique!