# Returning a populated array from a function that uses SwiftyJSON

Tags: function, swift, nsarray, swifty-json

I have a function that grabs information from a web service using SwiftyJSON. When I call the service using my DataManager class I am able to populate my array successfully and when I print it out it gives me what I want. However, I cannot return the populated array from my function because I think it's out of scope by the end of the function. Can anyone tell me how I can make my function return my populated array without being out of scope? If perhaps something else I'm doing wrong, any help would be appreciated.

```
func getEarthquakeInfo()->NSArray {
        var info = [AppModel]()

        DataManager.getEarthquakeDataFromFileWithSuccess {
            (data) -> Void in

                let json = JSON(data: data)


                if let JsonArray =  json.array {

                    for appDict in JsonArray {
                        var ids: String? = appDict["id"].stringValue
                        var title: String? = appDict["title"].stringValue
                        var time: String? = appDict["time"].stringValue
                        var information = AppModel(idEarth: ids, title: title, time: time)

                        info.append(information)
                    }


                }


           println("\(info)") // will print the results that I need


        }



        return info // This is an empty array
    }
```

This is a sample of what I get when it prints out apps:
ID: 146052, TITLE: M 1.7 Explosion - 0km E of Granite Falls, Washington, TIME: 2015-04-13 21:29:40 UTC,
DataManager4.swift file:

```
    let earthquakeURL = "http://www.kuakes.com/json/"
class DataManager {
    class func getEarthquakeDataFromFileWithSuccess(success: ((websiteData: NSData) -> Void)) {
        //1
        loadDataFromURL(NSURL(string: earthquakeURL)!, completion:{(data, error) -> Void in
            //2
            if let urlData = data {
                //3
                success(websiteData: urlData)
            }
        })
 }


    class func loadDataFromURL(url: NSURL, completion:(data: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void) {
        var session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

        // Use NSURLSession to get data from an NSURL
        let loadDataTask = session.dataTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler: { (data: NSData!, response: NSURLResponse!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
            if let responseError = error {
                completion(data: nil, error: responseError)
            } else if let httpResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {
                if httpResponse.statusCode != 200 {
                    var statusError = NSError(domain:"com.kuakes", code:httpResponse.statusCode, userInfo:[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey : "HTTP status code has unexpected value."])
                    completion(data: nil, error: statusError)
                } else {
                    completion(data: data, error: nil)
                }
            }
        })

        loadDataTask.resume()
    }


}
```

Comment: `getEarthquakeDataFromFileWithSuccess` is asynchronous. So it will execute the return statement before that function is completed. To fix this set up a completion block for your function. Here are some examples of that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29452563/how-do-i-return-something-from-alamofire/29452838#29452838 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28207185/why-cant-i-get-the-request-result-form-alamofire/28207366#28207366

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I solved it:

```
var info = [AppModel]()



    func getEarthquakeInfo(completion: (results : NSArray?) ->Void ){

        DataManager.getEarthquakeDataFromFileWithSuccess {
            (data) -> Void in

                let json = JSON(data: data)


                if let JsonArray =  json.array {

                    for appDict in JsonArray {
                        var ids: String? = appDict["id"].stringValue
                        var title: String? = appDict["title"].stringValue
                        var time: String? = appDict["time"].stringValue
                        var information = AppModel(idEarth: ids, title: title, time: time)

                        self.info.append(information)
                        completion(results: self.info)
                    }


            }

        }



    }
```